# How to write blob data to image file in Phonegap?

Tags: javascript, cordova, filewriter

I am trying to use the Phonegap FileWriter api to write blob data to an image file. Here is the code I am using to create the blob first:

```
function dataURItoBlob(dataURI) {
    var binary = atob(dataURI.split(',')[1]);
    var array = [];

    for(var i = 0; i < binary.length; i++) {
        array.push(binary.charCodeAt(i));
    }

    return new Blob([new Uint8Array(array)], {type: 'image/jpeg'});
}
```

I looked through all of the documentation on the FileWriter api and I simply could not understand it very much. Here is what I tried thus far:

```
function saveBlobToFile(blob) {
    // root file system entry
    var root = getFileSystemRoot();

    // writes a file
    write_file = function(writer) {
        // write to file
        writer.write(blob);   
    };

    // creates a FileWriter object
    create_writer = function(fileEntry) {
        fileEntry.createWriter(write_file, null);
    };

    var newId = makeId();

    // create a file and write to it
    root.getFile(newId + '.png', {create: true}, create_writer, null);
}
```

That bit I am not sure what is going on. When I try to run this on an iPad nothing happens. All I want to do is save the blob data to a randomly-generated filename with a ".png" extension. How can I do this properly, and where is the file saved afterwards?

Comment: Remove the following line: `return root;`

Comment: I didn't mean to leave that in. Just took it out :)

Comment: try inserting some logging, like they do here: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/deedubbu/1590941/raw/89f55f82123bca77c9538adef01ed3f9070705c3/file_cr_rm.html

Comment: Hi Arun,I am also facing the same problem, did u find any solution?